# typescript signature for (BaseClass) => class NewClass extends BaseClass{}

Tags: types, typescript

I would like to provide typings for a function that takes in the following snippet:

```
var expose = (BaseClass) => class NewClass extends BaseClass{}
```

I have tried many ways, but I am not able to make it work. Basically when I call the expose method, passing as argument any class type, it should return back an instance with all of the BaseClass methods plus the methods in the NewClass definition.

Is it possible with typescript?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, are you looking for generics to pass a type parameter?

Comment: BaseClass shoukd be a generic type. Conceptually it should be something Like <T>(BaseClass: T): T & NewClass => class NewClass extends BaseClass{}, But this does not work. Basically, any class passed to the function Will Return a new class that extends that class with some methods